# Huge VScode memory leaks (+ 1Gb / secondes)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, memory-leaks, electron, taskmanager

Today, VScode has a very weird bug in idle mod (no code running):

When I open it, it begin to eat memory up until my computer begin to lag.

The weird part is: if I close vscode, it will still go on in background and my ram utilisation will still increase until max load.

```
I checked my drivers -> all up to date
I checked malwares with an ESET scan -> nothing
I tried rebooting my computer and some basic stuff -> nothing
```

I know that vsCode use electron (maybe it's an electron problem?).

I have nothing fancy in vscode extension:

```
code runner
npm intellisense
path intellisense
plantuml
prettier
todo trees
vscode-icons
```

Here is my hardware config:

```
RAM: 32Go DDR4 3600MHz
CPU: ryzen 5 5600X
GPU: rx 6800 xt (msi)
Motherboard: B550 edge wifi
Stockage: 500Go SSD + 3To HDD
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvLTx.png) is a screenshot of my memory after opening vscode 10 secondes ago:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw1Ep.png) is a screenshot after I closed the application

Comment: I tried delete and reinstall vscode same bug

Answer (score 1):

My bad it was a virus (runned the long scan of eset scan and he detected it)

here is the malware location + name:

`C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\RMActivate_ssp_isv.exe variante de MSIL/Kryptik.ACAJ cheval de troie   nettoyé par suppression`